# Does the Java URIResolver concept exist in C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

In the Java XML transformation package, there is a concept known as a [URIResolver](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html), which is "An object that implements this interface that can be called by the processor to turn a URI used in document(), xsl:import, or xsl:include into a Source object."

So, if your XSL has an import like this

```
<xsl:import href="URI"/>
```

This allows you to take URI and map it to the [Source](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) of your choice - maybe it comes from a database, or maybe you want to map the URI to another URI.  This can be useful, since you can't use an `xsl:variable` in the `xsl:import href`.

Here is some sample Java code that creates a transformer and does a transform.

```
URIResolver uriResolver = new MyURIResolver();  // sample
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
transformerFactory.setURIResolver(uriResolver);
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setURIResolver(uriResolver);
transformer.transform(xml, result);
```

Note, there are two places in the code where the URIResolver is used:

- TransformerFactory
  [setURIResolver](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#setURIResolver(javax.xml.transform.URIResolver)) - "Set an object
  that is used by default during the
  transformation to resolve URIs used
  in document(), xsl:import, or
  xsl:include."
- Transformer [setURIResolver](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setURIResolver(javax.xml.transform.URIResolver)) - "Set
  an object that will be used to
  resolve URIs used in document()."

**Question**:  Is there a similar concept to the Java URIResolver in C# and .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`XmlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx).

`XmlResolver` is one of `System.Xml` abstractions, which means you can use it in various APIs, such as [`XslCompiledTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `XmlDocument`, `XmlReader` (via `XmlReaderSettings`), etc.

Here's a more in-depth on how it works, and how you can [implement your own resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302284.aspx).

By default, these various APIs use the [`XmlUrlResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.aspx), which can resolve URIs that start with `http://` and `file://`.

In addition, for resolving external entities, you can override the default [`ResolveEntity` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.resolveentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `XmlReader`.

Comment: Thanks.  XmlResolver is what I need to "process include and import elements found in XSL style sheets," and I also found that to enable the document() function, I need to create a XsltSettings object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163499.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the analog exists.
[IXmlNamespaceResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmlnamespaceresolver.aspx)
and also [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx), which implements the interface.

@Lame Duck, I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, this is _not_ the equivalent to the resolver classes in Java. This resolves a namespace prefix to its namespace, used in namespace bindings. They do not (and when implemented, should not) retrieve an external entity. Namespaces look like URLs, but are just name-parts, not actual locations somewhere.