# What is the difference between &#x00A0; and &#160;?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, space, html-entities

I have written one XSLT to transform xml to html. If input xml node contains only space then it inserts the space using following code.

```
<xsl:text>&#xa0;</xsl:text>
```

There is another numeric character which also does same thing as shown below.

```
<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
```

Is there any difference between these characters? Are there any examples where one of these will work and other will not?

Which one is recommended to add space?

Thanks,
Sambhaji

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`&#160;` is a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`&nbsp;`).

`&#xa0;` is just [the same, but in hexadecimal](http://www.google.com/search?q=0xa0%20in%20decimal) (in [HTML entities](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/), the `x` character shows that a [hexadecimal number](http://www.the-eggman.com/seminars/about_hex.html) is coming). There is basically no difference, `A0` and `160` are the same numbers in a different base.

You should decide whether you really need a non-breaking space, or a simple space would suffice.

Comment: So there is no difference between &#160; and &nbsp;?

Comment: Nope, not at all

Comment: I just a weird error in PHP due to the difference between `&#x00A0;` and `&#160;`. There was an space (" " not " ", encoded differently I guess) in an `if` block, causing from undefined variables to syntax errors. I noticed it thanks to VSCode when I rewrote the `if` statement and `Ctrl` + `D` didn't match the other line even though it was the same content.

Answer (score 14):

It's the same. It's a [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview).
`A0` is the same number as `160`. The first is in base 16 (hexadecimal) and the second is in base 10 (decimal, everyday base).