# GATE Tool: changing text during XML annotation

Tags: gate

I am trying to XML annotate my document, the XML tags of data are correct but the tool is adding some extra letters. Is there any way to fix it?

before tool:

> [image: before tool]

after tool:

> [image: after tool]

output setting:

> [image: output setting]

Comment: Sorry the question is too short - unclear what is asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It may be caused by the translation to XML. Aren't the extra characters just **xml entities**. For example `&#160;` is non-breaking space, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511286/1857897