# How to add space in XSL?

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am creating a pdf report file using a xsl. On the header I need a header image and the report title. I was able to make it. Now the problem is that rest of the report is overriding the image. I tried adding some blank row but its not working for me.

In xsl Header has a table in first row I am adding the Report Name and second row I am adding the image.

Comment: What library are you using to generate the PDF? Apache-FOP?

Comment: @alex Yes I am using the same. Can you help as I am really new to it and also to xsl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With Apache FOP, in order to output a space like `&nbsp;` in HTML you would have to insert `&#160;`.

So if you want to insert a blank line, you just have to write a `fo:block` whose contents is `&#160;` like this

```
<fo:block>&#160;</fo:block>
```

**Edit**

`&#160;` always worked for me, but you can also try with `&#x00A0;` to see if it works.

Otherwise you can use `fo:leader` to output a blank line, like this

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:leader />
</fo:block>
```

[`<fo:leader>`](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/obj_leader.asp) without any attributes will generate an empty line that will fit the whole page width, generating an empty line.

There is also an other way which involves specifying the amount of space needed before your block of text with the [`space-before`](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/xslfo_blocks.asp) attribute, like this

```
<fo:block>
    <!-- your header -->
</fo:block>
<fo:block space-before="1pt">
    blah blah
</fo:block>
```

Comment: I used it but it didn't worked in my case. i found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461649/how-to-insert-nbsp-in-xslt

Comment: <fo:leader/> is also not working. It is in header does it give problem?

Comment: Can you update your question with more detail about your xsl/xslfo file?

Comment: I am off from work right now... will definetly do it in the morning (Indian Time)... thnx a lot... :)