# how to adjust table cells properly in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to put my XML data into a tabular format using xsl(FOP) but it could not be done completely as the cells are overlapping when there is no text in cell.

Here is my xsl code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" />
<xsl:template match ="records">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
       <fo:simple-page-master master-name="list">
           <fo:region-body margin-left="50pt"
                      margin-top="50pt"
                      margin-bottom="50pt"
                      margin-right="50pt"></fo:region-body>
       </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>

   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="list">
       <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
           <fo:block text-align="center">
               <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" >
                   <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                             <xsl:if test="position()&lt;= 1">
                                <fo:table-row>

                                     <xsl:for-each select="./item">

                                    <fo:table-cell text-align="center"   border="2px">
                                        <fo:block color="green" font-family="monospace" font-size="10pt" padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="color">
                                   <xsl:choose>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 1 ">
                                         <xsl:text>black</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 2 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#333399</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 3 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#FF9900</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 4 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#96CCD8</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 5 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#19A347</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 6 ">
                                         <xsl:text>green</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:otherwise>
                                         <xsl:text>white</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="val"/>

                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>

                                    </xsl:for-each>

                                </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                         <xsl:for-each select="./list">
                         <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
                           <fo:table-row>
                           <xsl:for-each select="./item">
                            <fo:table-cell border="4px"  text-align="center">
                             <fo:block font-family="monospace"   border-style="solid"  font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap"   padding="5pt" space-before="5pt"  space-after="5pt">
                                <xsl:attribute name="background-color">
                                   <xsl:choose>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 1 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#C1BFC4</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 2 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#B1A1C8</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 3 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#F9CAA0</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 4 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#96CCD8</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 5 ">
                                         <xsl:text>#C2D89A</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="position() = 6 ">
                                         <xsl:text>green</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:otherwise>
                                         <xsl:text>red</xsl:text>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>
                                   </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
                             </fo:block>
                               </fo:table-cell>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                           </fo:table-row>
                           </xsl:if>
                       </xsl:for-each> 
                   </fo:table-body>
               </fo:table>
           </fo:block>
       </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<records>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Subject Number</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Monthly Dairy Contact</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>3-Month Safety Contact</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Annual visit</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>Suspected HZ follow-up Visit</val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>49210</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>x</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>15-sep-2012</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val></val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val></val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>49210</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>x</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>15-sep-2012</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>test</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val></val>
    </item>
</list>
<list>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>49210</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>x</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>15-sep-2012</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>test</val>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="jaXBValue">
        <val>test</val>
    </item>
</list>
</records>
```

And my XSL output is as follow :
[image]

Can any one modify my code so as to appear table properly not like I shown in my image.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you move the `border-style` and `background-color` properties from `fo:block` to `fo:table-cell`. That bit of the code can also be simplified by removing `xsl:text` elements:

```
<fo:table-cell border="4px" border-style="solid" text-align="center">
  <xsl:attribute name="background-color">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 1">#C1BFC4</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 2">#B1A1C8</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 3">#F9CAA0</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 4">#96CCD8</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 5">#C2D89A</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position() = 6">green</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>red</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <fo:block font-family="monospace" font-size="12pt" wrap-option="no-wrap"
        padding="5pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt">
    <xsl:value-of select="val"/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```